# Graduate-level reference on temporal point processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for a modern, graduate level, rigorous book on temporal point processes which also treats self-correcting point processes, and self-exciting point processes.

It would be even more interesting if the book was also pointing me to some research questions in the field.

Comment: Why was this closed? It looks like a perfectly normal reference request to me.

Comment: I have the same confusion as @NateEldredge . This post looks fine to me and temporal point process is not exactly sharing the same reference as general point processes. They have some special methods when doing survival analysis. I edited the OP's title and tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can briefly read a short introduction to decide whether you are interested in the theoretic side or application side of the research subject. Say [Rasmussen's Notes](http://people.math.aau.dk/~jgr/teaching/punktproc11/tpp.pdf).

If you are more interested in the theory, there is a two-volume standard text on theory of point processes. It includes a panoramic discussion on temporal/spatial process in Chap 14,15.

> Daley, Daryl J., and David Vere-Jones. An introduction to the theory
>   of point processes: volume I&II, 2ed, Springer, 2007.

If you are more interested in the application, there is a very popular book [ABG](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-68560-1) discusses a variety of applications of point processes in survival analysis.

> Aalen, Odd, Ornulf Borgan, and Hakon Gjessing. Survival and event
>   history analysis: a process point of view. Springer Science & Business
>   Media, 2008.